# call controller method from jsp and get model attributes in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Due to some reasons (existing design of application), i need to call a controller method  in a jsp using jsp include. I need to access the set attributes in controller in parent jsp.
Below is my controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"profile"})
@RequestMapping("/manageMyAccount")
public class MyPageDataController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void initData(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, HttpSession session)        {
    Profile profile = (Profile) session.getAttribute("profile");
    model.addAttribute("test", "success");
    model.addAttribute("profile", profile);
}
```

}

JSP Code:

```
jsp:include page="/mvc/manageMyAccount/"/>
```

I am trying to get data in jsp after above statement in jsp as `${test}`, but am getting blank.

Comment: Test is not set in any scope. Try ${profile.test}. Profile is in session.

Comment: Thanks but I am unable to get profile as well. using ${profile}

Comment: I need certain data/objects on this jsp and set in Controller as model attributes. How can I set those to scopes in controller. I dont want them in session.

Comment: I am able to get profile. but is there a way i can get "test" attribute in jsp?

Comment: What did you do that now you can get profile?

Comment: You should use request attributes instead of session

Comment: Nothing earlier i was not printing it. But looks like session attributes can be added to request before rendering the page but model attributes are not loaded to request.

Comment: I tried using request.getAttribute("test") to print and it gives me null. :(

Comment: You must set request attribute in controller first

Comment: Each controller needs a view, and I return a valid view (jsp) from controller now. and in the view jsp I am settingvar like this - c:set var="test" scope="request" value="${test}"/> . I still get null for test in parent jsp. when i saw page source i am getting c:set var="test1" scope="request" value="${test}"/> looks like this is not compiled and just included in the parent jsp. Any clue plz?

Comment: I do not see opening angle bracket <, even in your jsp include. Is it missing in your SO question/comment only or in your source code as well?

Comment: i missed it just in comments not in code . sorry for that :(

Answer (score 0):

you have to access that variable in a jsp

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initData(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, HttpSession session)        {
    Profile profile = (Profile) session.getAttribute("profile");
    model.addAttribute("test", "success");
    model.addAttribute("profile", profile);
    return "manageMyAccount";
}
```

and in "`manageMyAccount.jsp`" access var using `${test}`

Comment: tried this I am getting profile but not test. Any other pointers plz.